# How to determine that current element is window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I attach some event handler to different elements such as input, select ... and window. I need to check inside handler if current element is window or common html element. How should I make that check?

Example:

> inputTextEl.attachEvent("some event", handler);
>
> inputButtonEl.attachEvent("some event", handler);
>
> window.attachEvent("some event", handler);

```
 var handler = function (eventName) {
    return function () {
    var message = '[' + eventName + ']';
     if (window.event) {
        message += ' eventType: ' + window.event.type;

        var target = window.event.srcElement || window.event.target;
        var id = target.id;
        if (id == '') {
                  id = target.parentNode.id;
        }
        message += ' ;eventTarget: ' + id;
     } else {
           message += ' window.event - undefined';
     }
     console.log(message); 
}; };
```

Comment: What does it mean for a use to cause some event to apply to the `window` only?  If the event is clicking, for example, the user will click on *some specific HTML element* within the window.  It would be helpful if you could provide your actual use case, not just abstract code.

Comment: I need to log information about fired events to console. I want to get something like "eventType: onclick; eventTarget: elementId"

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for IE in function handler

```
alert(Window.event.srcElement.tagName );
```

And for Firefox and Chrome use

```
   alert(this.tagName);
```

Comment: In IE Window.event.srcElement = undefined if event was attached to window object. In FF and Ch event.target returns window but event.target.tagName is undefined because window object has no tag.

Comment: The window does not have a tag name. However, you can compare the two objects: `if (this === window) // do something`

Comment: I desided to pass current element to handler method like that:var handler = function (eventName, element) {...}. And check if(window.parent === element) than it is window html element else common html element. (Because window parent is poiner to itself)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers use `event.target`, others use `event.srcElement`:

```
function handler(ev) {
    var event = window.event || ev;
    var target = event.srcElement || event.target;
    // event has the lowest-level element that is the target of the event
}
```

Most events will never have `window` as their target, because you cannot click/mouseover/etc the window itself; instead, you perform those actions on specific elements within the window.

Comment: Ok, I have uniq function to attach any event to any alement (containes window) It doesn't matter can that event be rised for current element or not - because it is a uniq function. So I need to check type of element to wich I attach event

Comment: window will be the target eventually if the events bubble up the dom tree unless you cancel bubbling by returning false in the event handler.

Comment: @Torsten You are technically correct; `event.currentTarget` is used for bubbling, but it is not supported in older IE versions, and there doesn't seem to be any obvious replacement for it.  Also, running `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` when returning `false` in an event handler is a helpful *jQuery* feature, not normal JS behavior.

Comment: You are right. Returning false just cancels certain events, like click on links and submit on forms. I should have given a bit more thought to my comment. I didn't use jQuery in years, so thanks for the pointer that I can skip the stopPropagation and preventDefault calls.